# "Indexing" (in a mathematical sense) variables in R so that the correct variable is chosen in each iteration of a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have 28 variables. Each one of them is a vector of numeric class. The names of these vectors are sub_1, sub_2, sub_3, and on and on all the way down to sub_28.

**What I want to do with these vectors is to compute a system of 28 equations where, in each equation, only one of those vectors is involved.**

The right hand-side of each equation is the calculation that I want to make on each vector and the left hand-side is where I want to store the output of each calculation.

So this is what I do. First, I declare a vector of length 28.

> alpha = vector("numeric", 28)

**Each component of this vector is going to store the corresponding outputs of the calculations.**

> For example, I want to set alpha[**1**] equal to
>
> > 1 + length(**sub_1**)*(sum(log(**sub_1**/(1.5))))
>
> And I want to set alpha[**2**] equal to
>
> > 1 + length(**sub_2**)*(sum(log(**sub_2**/(1.5))))
>
> And so on. You get the idea.

I thought about using a 'for' loop. This is what comes to my mind:

> for (i in 1:28) {
>
> alpha[i] = 1 + length(**sub_i**)*(sum(log(**sub_i**/(1.5))))
>
> }

I know exactly what is wrong with this code. The compiler searches for a variable whose name is sub_i, and it won't find that variable because I haven't declared it. **What I want is for the compiler to read the _i as a subindex. I want the compiler to look —in each iteration of the loop— for the sub_i vector whose subindex i matches the number of the iteration.** How can I achieve that?

Edit: by the way, the 28 vectors have varying lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the 28 numeric variable vectors in a list and apply a function on all list elements. 
Simulated data:

```
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
# pick some random vector lengths
veclengths <- sample(50:100, 28, replace = TRUE) 
# generate random numeric values to generate the vectors
my.variables <- lapply(veclengths, function(x) rnorm(x,100,10))
# name the vectors as in your example (not required)
names(my.variables) <- paste0("sub_", seq_along(my.variables))
# extract these 28 separate vectors as individual variables for your use case
list2env(my.variables , envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

You could then load your vectors into a list, e.g.

```
vars <- ls(pattern="sub_.*") # pick variables by name pattern
# I sorted here numerically, for convenience
my.variables <- mget(vars[order(as.numeric(gsub("sub_", "", vars)))])
```

Then just apply the function you chose to all list elements separately

```
resfun <- function(x) {1 + length(x)*(sum(log(x/(1.5))))}
alpha <- unlist(lapply(my.variables, resfun))
```